# Setting Environment Variables for All Projects in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, ubuntu, environment-variables, qt-creator

I am running Qt Creator 3.1.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, and building a program which links to a library located in `/usr/local/lib`. Now in my `.bashrc` file, I have set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to include this directory, and then if I run my program from bash, it runs ok. However, if I try to run it from within Qt Creator (by pressing the green arrow), then I receive an error message that it cannot find the library.

So, my temporary solution is to go into `Build->Run Environment` and set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in there. However, I would need to do this on every new project, and since `/usr/local/lib` is a common directory for locally-installed libraries, this could become frustrating.

Is there any way in Qt Creator to set environment variables for all projects by default, rather than having to set it manually for each individual project?

Answer (score 2):

You can set environment variables per Kit. Open *Preferences*, go to *Build & Run*, select the *Kits* tab. Select the kit for which you would like to set the variable. In the properties list there is an item called *Environment*. Click on the Change button and enter your variables.

Comment: When I click on a kit (such as `Desktop (default)`), it lists a number of properties; however, none of them are `Environment`. The list is: `Name`, `Device type`, `Device`, `Sysroot`, `Compiler`, `Debugger`, `Qt version`, and `Qt mkspec`.

Comment: I just noticed that I have 3.4.2, not 3.1.1 installed. That must be the difference :(

Comment: Ok - I think I will just upgrade, perhaps it's not possible in 3.1.1!

Comment: Yes, that should help. See screenshot in official documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html